# how to decrease the execution time in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-raster

I stored large amount of Raster data ~ 100 MB deolali map in postgresql using raster2pgsql command. The primary key in deolali table is rid. I am using query st_clip from postgis extension and i am getting 9.6 seconds for the query to execute. I want to reduce the execution time in postgresql. How can i achieve this?

[en image deterscription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJxpI.png)

Comment: Get fast CPUs and keep the database in RAM.

Comment: Processing rasters as (e.g.) GeoTIFF files with GDAL will always be faster than working with PostGIS.